# COPY command runs but no data being copied from Teradata (on-prem)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am running into an issue where I have a set up a pipeline that gets a list of tables from Teradata using a Lookup activity and then passes those items to a ForEach activity that then copies the data in parallel and saves them as a gzipped file. The requirement is to essentially archive some tables that are no longer being used.

For this pipeline I am not using any partition options as most of the tables are small and I kept it to be flexible.

**Pipeline**

[image]

**COPY activity within ForEach activity**
[image]

99% of the tables ran without issues and were copied as gz files into blob storage, but two tables in particular run for long time (apprx 4 to 6 hours) without any of the data being written into a blob storage account.

[image]

Note that the image above says "Cancelled", but that was done by me. Before that I had a run time as described above, but still no data being written. This is affecting only 2 tables.

I checked with our Teradata team and those tables are not being used by any one (hence its not locked). I also looked at "Teradata Viewpoint" (admin tool) and looked at the query monitor and saw that the query was running on Teradata without issues.

Any insight would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: what is size of data in this table ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onlooking issue mention it look the data size of table is more than a blob can store ( As you are not using any partition options )

Use partition option for optimize performance and hold the data

[Link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/cloud-data/working-azure-blob-storage-service/)

Comment: Hi @sandeep rawat you are correct. Once I enabled parallelism I was able to copy the file into our blob storage. 
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else comes across this, the way I solved this was to create a new data store connection called "TD_Prod_datasetname". The purpose of this dataset is to not point to a specific table, but to just accept a "item().TableName" value.

This datasource contains two main values. 1st is the **@dataset().TeradataName**

**Dataset property**
[image]

I only came up with that after doing a little bit of digging in Google.

I then created a parameter called **"TeradataTable"** as String.

[image]

I then updated my pipeline. As above the main two activities remain the same. I have a lookup and then a ForEach Activity (where for each will get the item values):

[image]

However, in the COPY command inside the ForEach activity I updated the source. Instead of getting "item().Name" I am passing through @item().TableName:

[image]

This then enabled me to then select the "Table" option and because I am using Table instead of query I can then use the "Hash" partition. I left it blank because according to Microsoft documentation it will automatically find the Primary Key that will be used for this.

The only issue that I ran into when using this was that if you run into a table that does not have a Primary Key then this item will fail and will need to be run through either a different process or manually outside of this job.

Because of this change the previously files that just hung there and did not copy now copied successfully into our blob storage account.

Hope this helps someone else that wants to see how to create parallel copies using Teradata as a source and pass through multiple table values.